# Truncate title in ActiveAdmin show screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I would like to show an object's `name` attribute value as the title of the ActiveAdmin show screen. How to do it according to [ActiveAdmin: Customizing the Show Screen](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/6-show-pages.md) is:

```
show title: :name do
```

However, the value of the name may be very long, and I need to [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) it like:

```
show title: truncate(obj.name, length: 20) do
```

But this code does not work. How to truncate the title properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proc and pass the instance into the block.

```
show title: proc{ |obj| truncate(obj.name, length: 20) } do
```